# Custom Post Type Archive template not being called

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

My question is similar to a number of posts on this site, but I haven't found a solution to my specific issue yet.

I'm trying to implement an archive for a custom post type, "ttwi_course". I completed the following steps, which I've successfully performed on numerous other sites:

1. I registered the CPT, code below
2. I created an archive template, archive-ttwi_course.php
3. I created a single-ttwi_course.php
4. I created a WordPress Page called "Courses"

When I visit the Courses Page (http://localsite.dev/courses/) the page exists but uses the page.php template instead of archive-ttwi_course.php. When I visit a single ttwi_course post (http://localsite.dev/courses/course-1), it uses the correct single-ttwi_course.php template. I tried deleting the Courses WP Page, but http://localsite.dev/courses/ results in a 404.

Note that I've already tried flushing permalinks, adding and removing `flush_rewrite_rules();` after `register_post_type( 'ttwi_course', $args );`, changing themes, disabling plugins, and removing all code from the archive template. It's probably some dumb issue, but I have yet to find it.

Registered post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'ttw_register_course_post_type' );    
function ttw_register_course_post_type() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => __( 'Courses', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'singular_name'      => __( 'Course', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'menu_name'          => __( 'Courses', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => __( 'Course', 'add new on admin bar', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'add_new'            => __( 'Add New', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Course', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Course', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Course', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Course', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Courses', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Courses', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Course:', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No courses found.', 'ttwi-courses' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No courses found in Trash.', 'ttwi-courses' )
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'courses' ),
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => 25,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' )
);

register_post_type( 'ttwi_course', $args );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you describe is expected behavior based on your post type registration settings. A page isn't going to load an archive template, I'm not sure why you'd expect it to. Your rewrite argument slug is only for single posts. Setting `has_archive` to `true` uses the post type slug as archive location, which is `ttwi_course`. If you want the archive to be `courses`, then set `has_archive` to `courses`.

Comment: Thanks Milo. You're right, setting `has_archive` to `'courses'` works. I wonder why creating a Page previously had worked before?